# get multiple category in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table `company` data is :

```
id | name | email
 1 | abc  | any@any.com
 2 | xyz  | as@as.com
```

other table of `category` data is :

```
id | name
1  | cat1
2  | cat2
3  | cat3
```

and joined table of both category and company is `join_cat_company`

```
category_id | company_id | main
          1 |           1| 1
          2 |           1| 0
          3 |           1| 0
          2 |           2| 1
          1 |           2| 0
          3 |           2| 0
```

in joined table `main` is use for main category

i want result like :

```
  company_name | category
           abc | cat1,cat2,cat3
           xyz | cat2,cat1,cat3
```

the main category must be fist of the category list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   company.name AS company_name,
         CONCAT_WS(',',
           GROUP_CONCAT(  maincat.name),
           GROUP_CONCAT(othercats.name)
         ) AS category
FROM     join_cat_company
       JOIN company                ON join_cat_company.company_id  =   company.id
  LEFT JOIN category AS maincat    ON join_cat_company.category_id =   maincat.id
                                  AND join_cat_company.main = 1
  LEFT JOIN category AS othercats  ON join_cat_company.category_id = othercats.id
                                  AND join_cat_company.main = 0
GROUP BY company.name
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3269/1).

---

**EDIT**

Further to @lanzz's excellent [observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783151/get-multiple-category-in-a-single-row/10783183#comment14024438_10783183) above, you could simply do:

```
SELECT   company.name AS company_name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(
           category.name ORDER BY join_cat_company.main DESC
         ) AS category
FROM     join_cat_company
       JOIN company  ON  company.id = join_cat_company.company_id
  LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = join_cat_company.category_id
GROUP BY company.name
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3269/5).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` alone won't ensure that the `main` category appears first in the list.

Comment: Actually, according to the example in the docs, ordering with GROUP_CONCAT is straightforward: `mysql> SELECT student_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ') FROM student GROUP BY student_name;`; you can easily order by `join_cat_company.main DESC`.